# C++11: Thread pool for successive input reduction

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Consider a container of type T elements, e.g. `std::vector<T> input`, and an excessively time-consuming function `T f(const T&, const T&)`. I wish to apply `f` on `input` until one single element remains - in parallel.

I am new to C++ so I adapted an existing implementation for a [Thread pool pattern in C++11](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool) to my needs, in particular [this example](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/example.cpp).

**Code for discussion:**

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "ThreadPool.h"

template<class T>
T ParallelReduction(ThreadPool& pool, const std::vector<T>& input, const std::function<T(T,T)>& func)
{
    std::queue<std::future<T>> futureResults;
    std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(), [&futureResults](T e)
    {
        // T -> future<T>
        futureResults.push(std::async([e]{return e;}));
    });

    for (;;)
    {
        if (futureResults.size() > 1)
        {
            // Get two "old" partial results, forward them to func(T,T)
            T a = futureResults.front().get();
            futureResults.pop();
            T b = futureResults.front().get();
            futureResults.pop();

            futureResults.push(pool.enqueue([a, b, func]{return func(a,b);}));
        }
        else
        {
            // all input and partial result elements have been processed once, return the final result
            return futureResults.front().get();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ThreadPool pool(4);

    std::vector<int> input(12);
    int n = 0;
    std::generate(input.begin(), input.end(), [&n]{ return ++n; });

    auto sum = ParallelReduction<int>(pool, input, [](int a, int b){return a + b;});
    std::cout << sum << "\n";

    auto fibonacci = ParallelReduction<int>(pool, input, [](int a, int b){return a * b;});
    std::cout << fibonacci << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to implement this without introducing `futureResults`, i.e. a solution that works "inline" on `std::vector<T>& input`?
2. If not, can we optimize the way we assign values `T` to `std::future<T>` in the first part?
3. Is it more efficient to forward `std::future<T>` to our function `func` instead of `T`, i.e. let the child thread wait and access the value of `a` and `b` and not the main thread?
4. The parts inside the loop look awful - any ideas?
5. Where can I optimize the code?